# Sorting by element on data structure in python

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is any data structure in python that can fulfil my requirements.

I have a tuple of such

```
(item1, item2, item3, count)
```

I would like to sort by count in descending order. Is there any structure i could use in python to achieve this? The elements can be reordered if necessary.

Yes i have a list of tuples which will look like this above

Comment: Do you mean you have a list of tuples, where the tuples look like above?

Comment: Do you mean - sorting by indexes like  1(item1), 2 (item2)...?

Comment: sorted(tuple,reverse=True) will this solve your problem

Comment: Answered all the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list of tuples, where each tuple looks like -

```
(item1, item2, item3, count)
```

Then you can use `sorted()` function with `key` argument and `operator.itemgetter(3)` to get the 4th element from the tuple to sort based on , and `reverse=True` to sort in descending order. Example -

```
import operator
sorted(lst, key=operator.itemgetter(3),reverse=True)
```

You can also use `operator.itemgetter(-1)` , if you want to get the last element from the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

`sorted(tuple,reverse=True)` should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Given list of tuples:

```
l = [(a1, b1, c1, count1), (a2, b2, c2, count2), ...]
```

You may simply do:

```
l.sort(key=lambda t: t[-1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use your old friend lambda:

```
l.sort(lambda x,y:cmp(y[3],x[3]))
```

Where "l" is the name of your list.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> values = [
...     ('asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcv', 5),
...     ('qwer', 'asdf', 'zxcv', 9),
...     ('zxcv', 'qwer', 'asdf', 2)
... ]

>>> sorted(values, key=lambda value: value[3], reverse=True)
[('qwer', 'asdf', 'zxcv', 9),
 ('asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcv', 5),
 ('zxcv', 'qwer', 'asdf', 2)]
```